# Why deref coersion doesn't work for nested Vec?

Tags: rust

One can pass a `Vec` to function expecting a slice with implicit [coersion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods):

```rust
fn foo(arg: &[u8]) {}

foo(&vec![]); // compiles fine
```

Why this cannot be extended to nested slices and Vecs?

```rust
fn bar(arg: &[&[u8]]) {}

bar(&vec![&vec![]]); // Compilation error

// Can be worked around by explicit conversion to slices
bar(&vec![&vec![][..]][..]);
```

[Example in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6d19a66c837afe1af2a75ac20e3d1cf2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [dereferencing `Vec<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Deref) ([src](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#1885-1891)) results in `&[T]`, i.e. given `Vec<Vec<u8>>` it results in `&[Vec<u8>]` and not `&[&[u8]]`.

Ultimately, you'll need to [`map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map), [`deref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)/[`as_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_slice) and [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) to obtain `&[&[u8]]`:

```rust
let v: Vec<Vec<u8>> = ...;

let v = v.iter().map(std::ops::Deref::deref).collect::<Vec<_>>();
// or
let v = v.iter().map(Vec::as_slice).collect::<Vec<_>>();

bar(&v);
```

---

Alternatively depending on the context, you could change `bar()` into a generic function and accept [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html). Then both would be possible:

```rust
fn bar<I, T>(iter: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: AsRef<[u8]>,
{
    ...
}

bar(&vec![&vec![]]);
bar(&vec![&vec![][..]][..]);
```

---

The reason `&vec![&vec![]]` doesn't work, is because the inner `&` doesn't result in the `Vec<u8>` to dereference into `&[u8]`, but instead just references the `Vec` resulting in `&Vec<u8>`.

The outer `&` then doesn't work, because `bar` expects `&[&[u8]]`. But it receives `&Vec<&Vec<u8>>` and dereferencing to `&[&Vec<u8>]` still isn't what `bar` expects either. Thus why you receive the `mismatched types` error.

Your second example `&vec![&vec![][..]][..]` works, because you're explicitly causing both `Vec`s to be dereferenced to slices.
This can however be "simplified" into something more *readable* using [`as_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_slice), i.e. `bar(vec![vec![].as_slice()].as_slice());`.
However, ultimately to get a `&[&[u8]]` from an arbitrary `Vec<Vec<u8>>` you'd need to deref and collect into a new `Vec<&[u8]>`.

Related: ["What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)

Comment: To add context to this, it arguably makes sense you need the explicit `map/collect` because creating the `&[&[u8]]` is potentially going to allocate enough memory for all the `&[u8]`s and do work for each item in the original Vec. There could be a million `&[u8]`s in that Vec; you wouldn't want to use space and do work for each item implicitly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this exhaustive answer. It really helped me understand this. <3